# Exclude numeric values from report

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, regexp-like

I have a field named `statu` in the table `TB_ORDERS`.

If the field status has a **numeric value**, I should exclude that record from report - **only alphabetical should be shown**.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I should exclude that record from report - only alphabetical should be shown.

You could use **REGEXP_LIKE** in the filter predicate.

- `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[[:digit:]]+')`

Or,

- `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '\d+')`

Or,

- `NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[0-9]+')`

For example,

```
SELECT * FROM TB_ORDERS
WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[[:digit:]]+');
```

**Demo**

```
SQL> WITH TB_ORDERS AS(
  2  SELECT 'abc123abc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'abcabc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'abcabc123' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '123abcabc123' status FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM TB_ORDERS
  8  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[[:digit:]]+');

STATUS
------------
abcabc

SQL>
```

Or,

```
SQL> WITH TB_ORDERS AS(
  2  SELECT 'abc123abc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'abcabc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'abcabc123' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '123abcabc123' status FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM TB_ORDERS
  8  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '\d+');

STATUS
------------
abcabc

SQL>
```

Or,

```
SQL> WITH TB_ORDERS AS(
  2  SELECT 'abc123abc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'abcabc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 'abcabc123' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '123abcabc123' status FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM TB_ORDERS
  8  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[0-9]+');

STATUS
------------
abcabc

SQL>
```

**Update** On OP's request

```
SQL> WITH TB_ORDERS AS(
  2  SELECT '*abc123abc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 'ab*cabc' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '****' status FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '123abcabc123' status FROM dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT * FROM TB_ORDERS
  8  WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[0-9]+');

STATUS
------------
ab*cabc
****

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the answer.Just noticed that a set of status  has special character like * .So if I include  'NOT REGEXP_LIKE(status, '[0-9]+')',the status which has * is getting disappeared .Please help

Comment: @SitharaJayachandran No, it won't exclude `*`.  Please see the update in the answer. It works perfectly.